# How can I use CertificateUtility.kt and X509Utilities.kt to create keypair and certificates for a corda network?

Tags: corda

I am referring to the line : *You can use any standard key tools or Corda’s X509Utilities (which uses Bouncy Castle) to create the required public/private keypairs and certificates.* (from https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/3.1/permissioning.html#creating-the-root-and-doorman-cas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your questions, you will now need a PKI tool to create the required public/private keypairs and certificates.

However, if I am not mistaken, you are trying to build a private Corda network. Corda 4.5 currently offer 2 toolsets to start a network.

1. Corda network bootstrapper [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/network-bootstrapper.html). This is for non-production level quick PoC tool. And there is no doorman involved in this toolset. So you actually do not need to worry about the keypair and CA stuff.
2. Corda Enterprise Network Manager [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.3.html). This is production level tool set, which offers you the abilities to setup you network including the Keys and CAs

You are referring to the documentation for Corda 3.1 and now we are on Corda 4.5, we highly suggest you always follow the latest documentation as the code implementation might vary from version to version.